# Ajax Request from Template

Tags: module, ajax, json

I am trying to return json from a module method. Very simple example at this point.

```
public function mealDates()
{
    echo "{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}";
}
```

From the template

```
$.ajax({
    //request dates that are already taken
    type: "POST",
    url: "ACT=79",
    success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(e){

    }
});
```

If I declare dataType: 'json' returns error. If I don't I still am not getting the {"foo" :"bar"} from method. Suggestions on how to return json to template?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `send_ajax_response()` which will return JSON and works well for response to ajax requests. For your example you'd do

```
public function mealDates()
{
    $array = array(
        'foo' => 'bar', 
    );

    return $ee()->output->send_ajax_response($array);  
}
```